# PCL portable-Unsupported with NuGet

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, nuget, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I have create a PCL project and anytime that i try to add references from Nuget i have this error: (this error happens with all packages)

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.13'. You are trying
>   to install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-Unsupported', but the package does not contain any assembly
>   references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
>   For more information, contact the package author.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.13'. You are trying to install this package
>   into a project that targets 'portable-Unsupported', but the package
>   does not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.   at NuGet.ProjectManager.ExtractPackageFilesToProject
>   (IPackage package) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReferenceToProject (IPackage package)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute
>   (NuGet.PackageOperation operation) [0x00000] in :0
>   at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute (IPackage package,
>   IPackageOperationResolver resolver) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference (IPackage package, Boolean
>   ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference
>   (System.String packageId, NuGet.SemanticVersion version, Boolean
>   ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.SharpDevelopPackageManager.AddPackageReference
>   (IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean
>   allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.SharpDevelopPackageManager.InstallPackage
>   (IPackage package, ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction
>   installAction) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageManagementProject.InstallPackage
>   (IPackage package, ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction
>   installAction) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction.ExecuteCore ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.ProcessPackageAction.Execute ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageActionRunner.Run (IPackageAction
>   action) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.InstallPackage
>   (IEnumerable`1 packageOperations) [0x00000] in :0
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.InstallPackage ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.TryInstallingPackage ()
>
> ## [0x00000] in :0

that are information on my environment

```
=== Xamarin Studio ===

Version 4.2.2 (build 2)
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.5 ((no/964e8f0)
    GTK+ 2.24.20 theme: Raleigh
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 302050000

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 4.10.1 (Business Edition)
Android SDK: /Users/luigisaggese/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
    Supported Android versions:
        1.6   (API level 4)
        2.1   (API level 7)
        2.2   (API level 8)
        2.3   (API level 10)
        3.1   (API level 12)
        3.2   (API level 13)
        4.0   (API level 14)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.1   (API level 16)
        4.2   (API level 17)
Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 5.0.2 (3335.32)

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 7.0.5.2 (Business Edition)
Build date: 2013-02-12 20:04:08-0500

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.8.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Portable Class Libraries for Xamarin are supported from [NuGet v2.7.2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/11/13/pcl-and-net-nuget-libraries-are-now-enabled-for-xamarin.aspx).

I belive version 0.8 of Matt Ward's Xamarin Studio plugin is based on NuGet v2.7.2.

Installation instructions can be found here: https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin#installation